# Looping viewFinancials from quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I need some help with the **`quantmod`** package for R and the interaction with the for loop.
I have the vector `year`:

```
library(quantmod)
getFinancials("GE")
year <- colnames(viewFin(GE.f, "IS", "A"))
year
# [1] "2015-12-31" "2014-12-31" "2013-12-31" "2012-12-31"
```

The `viewFin` function gives me this output:

```
viewFin(GE.f, type="IS", period="A")["Net Income", year[1]]
# Annual Income Statement for GE
# [1] -6126
```

But if I try to loop by indexing the year I get this error:

```
> for(x in 1:4){
+   (viewFin(GE.f, type="IS", period="A")["Net Income", year[x]])
+   x=x+1
+ }

Annual Income Statement for GE
Annual Income Statement for GE
Annual Income Statement for GE
Annual Income Statement for GE
Error in viewFin(GE.f, type = "IS", period = "A")["Net Income", year[x]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

My idea is to make the date, the financial names (net income, equity, etc.), and the symbol) to create a data frame with companies in rows and year & financial as columns.

Does the `viewFin` function block the entry to the value of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you cannot alter an iterator inside a for loop in R. So your `x = x + 1` at the end of the for loop is unnecessary, and ignored.  Also note that auto-printing is disabled in for loops, so you need to explicitly call `print`.  Another thing you can do is iterate over a vector directly (there's no need to subset). So your for loop could look like this:

```
for(y in year) {
   print(viewFin(GE.f, type="IS", period="A")["Net Income", y])
}
```

That said, the for loop is unnecessary. You could get the same result using subsetting directly.

```
netIncome <- viewFin(GE.f, type="IS", period="A")["Net Income",]
```

It may be problematic to make a data.frame with symbols as rows, and line item and date as columns, because there's no reason each symbol should have the same number of years of data, or the exact same line items. It would probably be better to put all the data in long format first, until you know what you're working with.  Here's a function that does that for multiple symbols.

```
stackFinancials <-
function(symbols, type = c("BS", "IS", "CF"), period = c("A", "Q")) {
  type <- match.arg(toupper(type[1]), c("BS", "IS", "CF"))
  period <- match.arg(toupper(period[1]), c("A", "Q"))

  getOne <- function(symbol, type, period) {
    gf <- getFinancials(symbol, auto.assign = FALSE)
    vf <- viewFinancials(gf, type = type, period = period)
    df <- data.frame(vf, line.item = rownames(vf), type = type, period = period,
                     symbol = symbol, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
    long <- reshape(df, direction="long", varying=seq(ncol(vf)), v.names="value",
                    idvar="line.item", times=colnames(vf))
    rownames(long) <- NULL
    long
  }
  # combine all into one data.frame
  do.call(rbind, lapply(symbols, getOne, type = type, period = period))
}
```

And here's an example of using it:

```
R> Data <- stackFinancials(c("GE", "AAPL"), type = "IS", period = "A")
Annual Income Statement for GE
Annual Income Statement for AAPL
R> head(Data)
                               line.item type period symbol       time  value
1                                Revenue   IS      A     GE 2016-12-31 123693
2                   Other Revenue, Total   IS      A     GE 2016-12-31     NA
3                          Total Revenue   IS      A     GE 2016-12-31 123693
4                 Cost of Revenue, Total   IS      A     GE 2016-12-31  92508
5                           Gross Profit   IS      A     GE 2016-12-31  31185
6 Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total   IS      A     GE 2016-12-31  18377
R> tail(Data)
                                   line.item type period symbol       time value
387  Effect of Special Items on Income Taxes   IS      A   AAPL 2013-09-28    NA
388 Income Taxes Ex. Impact of Special Items   IS      A   AAPL 2013-09-28    NA
389            Normalized Income After Taxes   IS      A   AAPL 2013-09-28    NA
390        Normalized Income Avail to Common   IS      A   AAPL 2013-09-28    NA
391                     Basic Normalized EPS   IS      A   AAPL 2013-09-28    NA
392                   Diluted Normalized EPS   IS      A   AAPL 2013-09-28  5.68
```